# Bad substitution error in shell script while extracting directory

Tags: bash, docker, shell, teamcity, directory-structure

I am getting bad substitution error on running the following shell script. (Line numbers written just for reference):

Line 11> `SCENARIO_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"`

Line 12> `SCENARIO_PATH="${SCENARIO_DIR}/scenarios"`

The error in TeamCity is
`| ./k6-run-all.sh: line 12: syntax error: bad substitution`

Please note that on running this in local, I do not get this error and the scenario path is correctly extracted. But when I run this on TeamCity (which runs on Docker) it is giving me the above error.

Scenario path in my local is: `/Users/sonaliagrawal/Documents/antman/src/scenarios/full-card-visa`

Scenario path in TeamCity is extracting correctly despite the error which is:
`//scenarios/full-card-visa`

Solution tried:
Since in TeamCity, SCENARIO_DIR is itself just `/` hence I wrote an if then else to handle it, but it didn't help solve the substitution error, it just corrected the path to `/scenarios/full-card-visa`. The code I had added is as follows-

```
SCENARIO_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
echo "Scenario directory $SCENARIO_DIR"

SCENARIO_PATH=""
if [[ "$SCENARIO_DIR" = "/" ]]; then
   SCENARIO_PATH="/scenarios"
else
   SCENARIO_PATH="${SCENARIO_DIR}/scenarios"
fi
```

Reference:
In case it helps, Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM loadimpact/k6:0.34.1
COPY ./src/lib /lib
COPY ./src/scenarios /scenarios
COPY ./src/k6-run-all.sh /k6-run-all.sh
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["sh", "-c", "./k6-run-all.sh"]
```

Comment: Try adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your bash file.

Comment: Or, better, remove the bash-specific `${VARIABLE[n]}` syntax and bash-specific `$BASH_SOURCE` variable; you should be able to do this using purely POSIX shell syntax.  Then change the "shebang" line to `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: I tried to add #!/bin/bash to the top of my bash file, now it is not running at all. It is giving error as  `sh: ./k6-run-all.sh: not found`

Comment: Even closed questions should not have answers edited into them.

Answer (score -1):

It's because your script isn't being executed as a bash script. Put the following on the top of the .sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's literally the answer to the question.

Comment: No idea who downvoted it. 
But I tried to add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of my bash file, now it is not running at all. It is giving error as `sh: ./k6-run-all.sh: not found`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: That problem is because you're running a command that doesn't exist in your current working directory. It's not related to the script.

Comment: I fixed the issue by doing 3 steps:
1. installed bash in docker, for doing so after entrypoint, I added the following 2 lines in Dockerfile:
USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

2. I added the shebang on top of bash file: #!/bin/bash

3. I changed Dockerfile's last line to run bash:
CMD ["bash", "-c", "./k6-run-all.sh"]